# Calculating impedance

Tags: resistors, impedance, capacitance, inductance, series

I would appreciate if someone could verify my reasoning for the following question please. Thank you, much appreciated.

**Question**:

A series R-L-C circuit has a resistance of 8 Ω, an inductance of 120 mH and a capacitance of 5 μF. If the current flowing is 2A, calculate the impedance of the circuit.

**The way I worked it out**:

\$Z = \sqrt{R^2 + (2πCL)^2}\$

\$Z = \sqrt{(8Ω)^2 + (2π \times 5\times10^{-6}F \times 1.2\times10^{2}H)^2}\$

\$Z = 8Ω\$

Does make sense at all? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention... what is confusing me is why I was given the current, when you don't really need it for the calculation.

Comment: You need the value of frequency to calculate impedance, not current. Either the question is wrong or you've transcribed it incorrectly.

Comment: I edited your post to format your formulas with MathJax, but it is wrong: the impedance of the capacitor and of the inductor depend on the frequency, which you did not give. Moreover, \$120 \textrm{mH} ≠ 1.2 \times 10^2 \textrm{H}\$.

Comment: @user2233709, are you sure? 120milliHenries = 1.2 x10^2 Henries no? I took the circuit to be resonant since I was not given a frequency. What do you think?

Comment: @greenhorn I assumed the circuit to be resonant as I stated in my answer below. But, as 2233709 said, this makes "2A current flowing" info useless.

Comment: Question makes no sense. I think you really need to understand how impedance work with C and L first.

Comment: @greenhorn Yes, I am sure, \$120 \textrm{mH} = 1.2 \times 10^2 \textrm{mH} = 1.2 \times 10^{-1} \textrm{H}\$

Answer (score 1):

Impedance of the circuit equals to resistor value, which is 8 Ohms in your question; **but under resonance**.

Because at the resonance frequency, the impedance formula turns to:

\$Z = \sqrt{R^2 + (\omega L - 1/(\omega C))^2}\$ where \$\omega = \sqrt{LC}\$.

Resonance condition is not given in OP's question but I assumed that the circuit is resonant because the frequency is not given.

Comment: But the resonance assumption makes the question trivial and the provided current useless… This looks very strange for homework…

Comment: The current is stated as 2A - a real current, not a complex current, so the assumption of a resonance condition is perfectly valid. Perhaps this was the point of the question - can you see the wood for the trees?

Comment: @Jim Dearden Unless any info about voltage is given no info can be recovered from current stated to be 2A. More: _current flowing 2A_ as written could pretty much be as modulus and, also here, no info about its phase can be safely assumed. In short: total nonsense homework out of its context, possibly recovering al little bit if read embedded in its book chapter our class.